# Variable input from Form when opening Report

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2013

**Exist:**

1. A query with data and one of the columns is criteria based off of user input (i.e. [please choose a number:])
2. A report, based on that query, that asks for the same user input when opened.
3. A form with buttons to open said report and others and also a combo box based on a table.

Is it possible to make it so that when the button was pressed (to open the form), while a value was picked in the combo box, then the report that is loading will use the combo box value instead of asking the user for input?

I tried creating such action with both the Macro Builder and the Expression Builder in the OnClick button property. But failed.

Is this attainable in VB code? Is it even possible at all?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the bound column of your combo box is the value that you wish to use to filter the query, simply change the query criteria from `[please choose a number:]` to instead reference the value held by your combo box, e.g.:

`[Forms]![YourForm]![YourComboBox]`

Comment: Am I right to assume that the criteria in the query has to be removed? No option to leave it as is and use the associated pop-up as a receptacle for whatever in the box?

Comment: Correct. You are only prompted to specify a parameter value because Access cannot locate a field called `please choose a number:`. Therefore, you will either need to remove this criteria or change the name of your combo box to `please choose a number:`

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful.
This seems... a bit counter intuitive since I created the Form and the Report only AFTER I made my Query.
Also, the Query is now useless - as opening it gives an empty table instead of asking for a value and then presenting the relevant information. However, that's a small cookie to crack.